# Google App Engine PHP File Upload Broken

Tags: php, google-app-engine, zend-framework, file-upload, fatal-error

Zend 1.9 project, using code right from the docs/examples for the PHP environment. My image upload used to work well, but now this is what I'm getting:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method

google\appengine\api
      \cloud_storage
      \CloudStorageTools::parseFilename()
in

/base/data/home/runtimes
     /php/sdk/google/appengine/ext
     /cloud_storage_streams
     /CloudStorageStreamWrapper.php on line 143
```

Sounds like it's out of my code's hands, no?! Ideas?

I've also posted this question on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/RjMZxn8qteM but those boards seem a bit dead...

Answer (score 0):

After updating PHP SDK locally, it all seems to work.

(I'm not sure why that is, though, as the SDK that I use locally doesn't get referenced on production. I always assumed those libraries were auto loaded on the live servers, although the classes do get uploaded along with my app. Weird...)

Comment: You're right - that class is auto-loaded, not deployed with your application.